# Rstudio. Cores num conjunto de BoxPlots

Tags: r

Criei este conjunto muito simples de boxplots mas pretendia melhorá-lo, nomeadamente colorindo cada um deles e, eventualmente melhorar o código. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda. Deixo aqui o código que criei.

Obrigado.

```
> a<-c(0, 15, 10, 10)
> b<-c(16,21,2,14)
> c<-c(30,3,11)
> d<-c(0, 14, 18, 3)
> e<-c(27,44,0)
> f<-c(33,2)
> g<-c(1, 1, 0)
> h<-c(32,3)
> i<-c(2,1,0)
> j<-c(31,4)
> k<-c(3,1,0)
> l<-c(0,18,16,1)
> m<-c(0,13,20,2)
> n<-c(0,16,17,2)
> o<-c(32,3)
> p<-c(2,1)
> q<-c(1,0,20,14)
> r<-c(12,23)
> s<-c(6,16,13,0,0)
> t<-c(7,16,12,0,0)
> u<-c(7,15,13,0,0)
> v<-c(0,19,16)
> x<-c(0,17,18)
> z<-c(0,13,17,5)
> w<-c(27,8,0,0)
```

> boxplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [BoxPlots - rstudio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312184/boxplots-rstudio)

Answer (score 5):

Crie um vetor com as 25 cores.

```
 cores=c('blue', 'red', 'pink', 'orange', 'gray',
         '#fb5772', '#d953bd', '#c26a31', '#919c75', '#d312b4', 
         '#4549e5', '#6f95ef', '#f15050', '#54c2de', '#8f2e78', 
         '#1412ef', '#9f8e03', '#e86255', '#6e2802', '#318f5d', 
         '#9d0cee', '#95b631', '#376ab5', '#ed53c0', '#a76600')

 boxplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w, col = cores)
```

Pode usar algum dos links abaixo para obter as cores:

http://www.color-hex.com/random.php

http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/color.php

http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=Reds&n=3

[image: img]

Answer (score 5):

Para tornar a análise mais organizada, você pode fazer o seguinte:

**1)** crie um `data.frame` com todas as suas variáveis. Mas, como cada vetor tem tamanhos diferentes, faça:

```
library(qpcR)
x<-qpcR:::cbind.na(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w)
```

e, após:

```
dataset<-data.frame(x)
```

**2)** empilhe suas variáveis, de modo a criar grupos (ou `factors`). Por exemplo:

```
stacked<-stack(dataset)
head(stacked)

  values ind
1      0   a
2     15   a
3     10   a
4     10   a
5     NA   a
6     16   b
```

**3)** crie os boxplots:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
color<-colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(name='Dark2', n = 8))(25) #8 é um valor fixo; 25 é o número de vetores (a:w)

library(car)
Boxplot(values~ind,id.method='y',col=color,data=stacked)
```

**4)** o resultado fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]