# BoxPlots - rstudio

Tags: r

Pretendia colorir os vários boxplots subjacentes ao código que fiz (que deixo aqui) mas estou com alguma dificuldade. Se for possível alguém dar alguma info de como devo fazer, agradeço. Obrigado

```
> a<-c(0, 15, 10, 10)
> b<-c(16,21,2,14)
> c<-c(30,3,11)
> d<-c(0, 14, 18, 3)
> e<-c(27,44,0)
> f<-c(33,2)
> g<-c(1, 1, 0)
> h<-c(32,3)
> i<-c(2,1,0)
> j<-c(31,4)
> k<-c(3,1,0)
> l<-c(0,18,16,1)
> m<-c(0,13,20,2)
> n<-c(0,16,17,2)
> o<-c(32,3)
> p<-c(2,1)
> q<-c(1,0,20,14)
> r<-c(12,23)
> s<-c(6,16,13,0,0)
> t<-c(7,16,12,0,0)
> u<-c(7,15,13,0,0)
> v<-c(0,19,16)
> x<-c(0,17,18)
> z<-c(0,13,17,5)
> w<-c(27,8,0,0)
boxplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w)
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro temos que saber quantas caixas há nesse gráfico. Bastou copiar a instrução `boxplot` e substituir o comando gráfico por `length(list(etc))`.

```
length(list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w))
#[1] 25
```

Agora, é só usar o argumento `col` com um valor adequado.

```
boxplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z,w, col = rainbow(25))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há várias outras formas de escolher as cores. Sugiro que comece com `help("rainbow")` e siga os links aí.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o código abaixo para colorir as caixas. Mas pode utilizar também bibliotecas mais robustas como ggplot ou ggplot2. No exemplo abaixo foi colorida cada caixa individualmente, assim como a borda. Basta seguir o exemplo para todas as variáveis.

```
   boxplot(
   a,
   col = "lightgray",
   border=c("blue"),
   ylim = c(0, 45),
   xlim = c(0, 25),
   at = 1:1 
 )
 boxplot(
   b,
   col = "lightgray",
   border=c("green"),
   ylim = c(0, 45),
   xlim = c(0, 25),
   at = 1:1 + 1,
   add = TRUE
 )
 boxplot(
   c,
   col = "lightgray",
   border=c("red"),
   ylim = c(0, 45),
   xlim = c(0, 25),
   at = 1:1 + 2,
   add = TRUE
 )
 boxplot(
   d,
   col = "lightgray",
   border=c("blue"),
   ylim = c(0, 45),
   xlim = c(0, 25),
   at = 1:1 + 3,
   add = TRUE
 )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]