# Rstudio - BoxPlot

Tags: r

Tenho um gráfico com um conjunto de 3 BoxPlot que aparecem todos, em função do código que fiz, em "cinzento" e não consigo mudar essa cor. Deixo aqui o código que tenho no script. Pedia uma ajuda para resolver esta questão. Obrigado.

C=list(performances_desempenho_NN$Desempenho.rel,performances_desempenho_SVM$Desempenho.rel,performances_desempenho_RF$Desempenho.rel)
names(C)=c("NN","SVM","RF")
boxplot(C,col = rgb(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))

Vidal

Comment: Duplicata --> [Boxplot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/311949/rstudio-cores-num-conjunto-de-boxplots/316410#316410)

Comment: Abra o link (nele, contém o que procuras): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/311949/rstudio-cores-num-conjunto-de-boxplots